# Java (Length of an input)

Tags: java

So I want to get the length of the input in java, but the (String.length()) doesn't produce a satisfying result.
So when I type this code:

```
String c = "hi hello";
        System.out.print(c.length());
```

I get 8 which is correct
but when I type this code:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String c = s.next();
        System.out.print(c.length());
```

For "hi hello" is the input, I get 2 not 8. I tried again with different inputs and I found that string.length() have a problem with spaces in inputs. for example, if the input was "123456 78" the output would be 6 not 9. Can you tell me how to get the full length of the input?  Thanks in advance

Comment: `next()` returns the next token, and by default `Scanner` tokenize on spaces. You want `nextLine()`.

Comment: Use `nextLine()` instead, will return everything until it reaches `\n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `s.next()` to `s.nextLine()` and you will get the desired result.

- `next()` finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.
- `nextLine()` returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

---

```
-> "123456 78"
s.next().length() -> "123456".length() -> 6
s.nextLine().length() -> "123456 78".length() -> 9
```

Comment: Why am I downvoted? Tell me and I improve my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Use nextLine() rather than next() as next() can read the input only till the space.

nextLine() reads input including space between the words (that is, it reads till the end of line \n)

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String c = s.nextLine();
System.out.print(c.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

> The java.util.Scanner.next() method finds and returns the next
>   complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and
>   followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

The delimiter here is " ".

You get 2 as length because it says the length of "hi" is 2. If you
want the length of complete string use nextLine() it counts upto "\n"