# control not entered in for loop.not able to get the reason?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;


class ShootOut{

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int test=sc.nextInt();
        while(test!=0){
            int count=0;
            String s1=sc.next();  
            for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++){            
                if(s1.charAt(i)==2 && s1.charAt(i+1)==1){
                    count++;
                }       
            }     
            System.out.println(count);
            test--;
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35994188/6020034 for the answer.  This is a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java (Length of an input)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994158/java-length-of-an-input)

Comment: Without mdo123 comment.. I was not able to get your problem.  @Khushi you have to better elaborate your question, I think that improving your English is also mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Please review the comparisons

```
s1.charAt(i)==2
```

and

```
 s1.charAt(i+1)==1
```

If you would like to compare a character in the `String` `s1` with another char (here `1` or `2`), you should use ticks like

```
if(s1.charAt(i)=='2' && s1.charAt(i+1)=='1')
```

Comment: oh yeah i missed that apostrophe.